# What are some very useful JQuery plugins for social networking sites?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, templates

Any suggestions would be nice.

Comment: Your question is a little vague. What's your social networking sites look like? Different social sites will need different functions.

Comment: Since there's no _right_ answer here, why don't you make it a community wiki?

Comment: @Jeriko CW has been removed, because most of the time you need it, the question is probably inappropriate and doesn't belong anyway

Comment: fair enough.. though I would expect scenarios where people might get massive rep unduly now. oh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some suggestions here : [23 Facebook Style Plugins](http://www.jquery.wisdomplug.com/jquery-plugins/facebook-jquery-plugins/23-best-jquery-facebook-style-plugins/)